# Why does my disk drive access slow so much after adding a new drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

Originally my system had two SATA disk drives - I added an extra SATA disk drive to my system and when accessing this disk it sometimes take about 50 times longer to access the drive. (Windows Explorer can take about 2 mins to populate the basic directory and there is nothing special about the directory)

This doesn't happen all the time, but can't identify a pattern at the moment.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

(Using Windows Vista Home Premium - PC is custom made - this is just on my development PC. What other useful info can I give?)

Answer (score 1):

After double checking all the cables, you could try to test the drive with the dedicated software from the producer, like:

- [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools) for Seagate
- [Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=606&sid=3&lang=en) for WD

Comment: Also look at SpinRite, it is possible you got a bad drive right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the BIOS settings are different for the disk you added. We have had problems with slow SATA disks due to the BIOS being set to use a legacy mode.